# UMVUE for $\theta$ parameter of geometric distribution

Tags: self-study, estimation

Let $X_1,X_2$ be a sample from $Geo(\theta)$ ($0<\theta<1$).

I need to find the UMVUE for $\theta$.

I started with establishing that $Y=X_1+X_2$ is a sufficient complete statistic for $\theta$ and $Y\sim NB(2,\theta)$.

From the Lehmann–Scheffé theorem, this means that Y is UMVUE for $E(Y)=\frac{2}{\theta}$.

But that is not what I need. What should be my next step?

I also know that the MLE of $\theta$ is $\frac{2}{Y}$. Since it is a function of $Y$ alone, it should be UMVUE for $E(\frac{2}{Y})$ but how do I compute this to check if it is $\theta$?

Comment: I'm assuming you're dealing with the "number of trials" formulation of the geometric rather than the 
"number of failures" version (otherwise you're taking reciprocals of variables that may be $0$). You can immediately tell that $2/Y$  can't be unbiased for $\theta$. If $Y/2$ is unbiased for $1/\theta$ and $\text{var}(Y)>0$ then $2/Y$ must be biased for $\theta$ (e.g. by Jensen's inequality, or even just from the (hopefully obvious) fact that $\text{Cov}(X,1/X)<0$ (given $X$ is not constant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a different approach, consider the estimator,

$$ T(X_1, X_2) = \begin{cases}1 & X_1 = 1\\
0 & otherwise \end{cases} $$

This is unbiased for $\theta$ (why?). Then, by Lehmann-Scheffe, condition on your complete sufficient statistic, $E[T(X_1,X_2) | X_1 + X_2]$ to get the UMVUE. Finding the exact closed form of $E[T(X_1,X_2) | X_1 + X_2]$ will take a tiny bit of work though.

Comment: Actually, the first part of the problem (which I did already) is to show that $T(X_1,X_2)$ as you defined it is unbiased for $\theta$. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. So using the theorem you gave, I worked the estimator out as $\frac1{(\sum_{i=1}^2x_i)-1}$. Do you have any tips on finding the variance of the estimator?